# how to trim a string using special character as start point

Tags: c#, string, trim

I want to trim a string using $ as starting point means my string contains 2 $ signs i want to trim and remove the whole string before second $.
example strings are below

first string:

```
1 max CPC change(s)
time warner cable: Max CPC decreased from $2.25 to $1.50
```

this is my string i want to trim it to get only "$1.50"

second string

```
 Mobile Highend: Platform bid adjustment changed from +0% to +15%
```

trim to get only +15%

```
 change = source[4]
```

this is where it is filling my model property. how should i trim it here in c#

Comment: In your second example you would only get `%` because `+15` appears before `%`. Can you clarify?

Comment: @rao did you disappear?  Please choose an answer or post more questions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Regex will handle both results:

```
var result = from Match match in Regex.Matches(line, ".*to (.*)") 
             select match.ToString();
```

> 1 max CPC change(s)
>
> time warner cable: Max CPC decreased from $2.25 to $1.50

Results in `$1.50`

> Mobile Highend: Platform bid adjustment changed from +0% to +15%

Results in `+15%`

Comment: As most answers have missed this, if you wanted to use substring you could do it like this: `int index = s.LastIndexOf("to "); if (index > 0) s = s.Substring(index);`

Answer (score 0):

first string use `LastIndexOf("$")` and second string use `LastIndexOf("+")`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
        var str = "1 max CPC change(s)\ntime warner cable: Max CPC decreased from $2.25 to $1.50";
        var str1 = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("$") + 1);
        var str2 = str1.Substring(str1.IndexOf("$"));
        Console.WriteLine(str2);

        var str10 = "Mobile Highend: Platform bid adjustment changed from +0% to +15%";
        var str11 = str10.Substring(str10.IndexOf("%"));
        var str12 = str11.Substring(5);
        Console.WriteLine(str12);
```

Answer (score -1):

Without going into overkill with Regex, you can use `LastIndexOf` quite easily:

```
string s = "time warner cable: Max CPC decreased from $2.25 to $1.50";
int index = s.LastIndexOf("$");
if (index > 0)
{
    s = s.Substring(index);
}
Console.WriteLine(s); // $1.50
```

Comment: That doesnt get the second example

Comment: @paqogomez What's the problem? In the second example use `"+"` as the symbol.

Comment: @paqogomez I feel that would be insulting to ones intelligence.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the following methods

String.SubString()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx

String.LastIndexOf()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d.aspx

String.IndexOf()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx

Comment: @SonerGönül well he had shown no sign of trying anything. I did not want to just spoon-feed him the answer